# Javascript: indexOf with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

How can I check whether the page url contains a '#' character **plus some random digits**

> e.g. www.google.de/#1234

```
if( window.location.href.indexOf('#') > 0 ){
  alert('true');
}
```

Does indexOf support Regular Expressions?

Comment: Why do you need to know the index of it? Just use the `.match()` function to test if the regexp matches?

Comment: Can't you just test what's in `window.location.hash`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) to get the index of a regex:

```
'https://example.com/#1234'.search(/#\d+$/); // 20
```

And [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) if used for boolean checks:

```
/#\d+$/.test('https://example.com/#1234'); // true
```

The regex used for these examples are `/#\d+$/` which will match literal `#` followed by 1 or more digits at the end of the string.

As pointed out in the comments you might just want to check `location.hash`:

```
/^#\d+$/.test(location.hash);
```

`/^#\d+$/` will match a hash that contains 1 or more digits and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.